# Accordion - Auto toggle expand/collapse arrow not correctly adjusting when clicked

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu, accordion, expand

I'm working on accordion functionality for my company's website to showcase features/benefits interactively on our webpage. I've made some progress where the arrow does move down and to the side when the accordion expands/collapses. However, I am encountering a number of issues getting it to function correctly. It works perfectly when I click and re-click on an individual accordion, meaning that the arrow goes down and to the side upon expanding/collapse. However, I experience a number of issues when I go from one accordion to another.

1. When I click on another accordion (e.g. accordion below the original accordion I clicked on), the expand/collapse works, but the arrow does not adjust to reflect the state of the accordion functionality (e.g. the arrow does not drop).
2. When I click on an accordion that is two places below the original accordion, the functionality seems to work as desired. Therefore it is not consistent across several accordions that have been setup. For example, I have 10 accordions setup on the page I am working on.

Can anyone help with why this is happening, and what I'm missing in my code? JS, CSS and Accordion Module Code are below:

**JS:**

```
$('.body-container-wrapper').find('script:not(script[type="IN/Share"])').remove().end().wrapAll('<div id="site-wrapper"></div>');

$('.accordion-content').hide();
$('.expand .accordion-content').show();
$('.accordion-title').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.hs_cos_wrapper_type_custom_widget').siblings().find('.accordion-content').slideUp();
    $(this).closest('.hs_cos_wrapper_type_custom_widget').siblings().find('.hs-accordion-wrapper').removeClass('expand');
    $(this).parent().addClass('expand');
    $(this).next().slideToggle(250);
    var title = $('.accordion-title');
    title.each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('expand');
    });
   });        
});
```

});

**Accordion Module Code:**[accordion image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZQ4C.png)

```
<div class="hs-accordion-wrapper clearfix {% if widget.expand %}expand{% endif %}">
    <div class="accordion-title">
        <h4>{{ widget.title }}</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="two-col-right-wrapper clearfix accordion-content">
    <div class="feature-text col1">
        <div class="feature-image">
            {% if widget.left_column_image.src %}
                <a title="{{ widget.left_column_image.alt }}" href="{{ widget.left_column_image.src }}" rel="lightbox">
                    <img src="{{ widget.left_column_image.src }}" width="{{ widget.left_column_image.width }}" height="{{ widget.left_column_image.height }}" alt="{{ widget.left_column_image.alt }}">
                </a>
            {% endif %}
            <br>
            click the image above to view larger version
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="feature-text col2">
        {{ widget.right_column_content }}
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you modify your question so it doesn't have a load of pre-rendered markup and unrelated code, and just include a basic example that will run in a snippet on this page (without the need for images)?

Comment: my question has been edited. Don't know how to add a basic example that will run in a snippet.

Answer (score 0):

$(“.variation_form_section .select div”).on(‘click’, function() {

```
   $(this).addClass(‘active’).siblings().removeClass(‘active’);
```

});

css:

by default hide the content and when active class is added display it.
for dropdown when active class added

.active:after {

```
color: #ACD4CE;
-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
-o-transform: rotate(180deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
transform: rotate(180deg);
```

}

please let me know if you need anything.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm not sure I understand your instructions. What should I do exactly?